# Replace value by fkey after moving data to related table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

A numeric column should be extended to hold multiple values, i.e. reference some different entity. SQL only (Postgres specifically if no standard solution available).

Schema now:

```
Table X with columns ID, VAL, STUFF
Table Y with columns ID, VAL1, VAL2
```

What I want to achieve:

```
Table X with columns ID, YID, STUFF
Table Y won't be altered (neither existing data touched)
```

Table Y gets inserts for all rows of table X where X.VAL should be inserted as Y.VAL1. Y.ID auto-incremented, Y.VAL2 may remain NULL. Table X should then be updated to hold Y's ID as foreign key X.YID instead of the actual value X.VAL that is now stored in Y.VAL1.

Somehow I think it has to be possible to achieve that with a clean SQL-only solution. What I've found so far:

- create some PG/SQL script: just loop over table X, insert the stuff to table Y row by row returning the ID and updating table X
- plain SQL: get the number of entries in table Y, INSERT INTO Y with SELECT FROM X ... ORDER BY ID, INSERT INTO X with SELECT FROM Y ... skipping the number of entries that have been there before so the order should remain stable. I really don't like that solution. Sounds dirty to me.

Any suggestions? Or better go with PG/SQL?

TIA

Comment: Is there any data in table Y or it's  empty?

Comment: There's data in it.

Comment: Should this existing rows be referenced from new X when coverting old X schema to new one?

Comment: Well, the values get moved to Y and yes, those rows should be referenced by X then (that's the table YID I introduced instead of VAL - the value gets moved to Y, Y's ID is then stored in X's column YID).

Answer (score 1):

There is a third option: a single SQL statement. Postgres allows DML within a CTE. So create a CTE that performs the insert and returns the generated id. Use the returned id in the main query which updates the original table. This then does what you are looking for in a single SQL statement.

```
with cte as
      ( insert into y(val1) 
         select val  
           from x 
          returning y.id, y.val1
      ) 
update x 
   set val = cte.id
  from cte
 where x.val  = cte.val1;
```

Then assuming you want to maintain referential integrity:

```
   alter table x 
       add constraint x2y_fk 
       foreign key (val)
       references y(id) ;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0766e8f74066a4e77e50e5fe47905f71): Note: The demo copies both val and stuff from table x into table y. This was strictly for demonstration purposes and is **not** necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer!

I've thought of somethink like that but did not find a solution if val1 was not unique. As far as I can see, that's still an issue here? I could compare all columns (stuff is just a placeholder for a bunch of columns) but was hoping there's a cleaner solution.